# Wordpress website redirects to "index.html" which doesn't exisit

Tags: html, wordpress

My Wordpress website, www.the-family-historian.net, goes directly to /index.html, which doesn't exist. I have it set in the Wordpress backend so that the landing page is the posts (blog) and not a static page, but this "index.html" seems to be blocking it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This should force any request to go to `index.php` first and ignore `index.html`, not a 301 redirect though.

Answer (score 0):

Using an FTP program, or possibly a web based file manager, view the files that make up your website. Find an option to view "system / hidden files" in order to view the .htaccess file.  I suspect you will find a rewrite rule in it pointing to index.html    Simply change that to index.php and all should be good.

Comment: I thought that might be an issue, but it appears to be listed like this:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>`